# Downloading variables from Matlab's workspace to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, com, com-interop

I have a workspace called "mat.mat" and I have to download names of variables from that to C# via Console Application. I have a problem, when I have the list of variables in `struct`, I've tried using `GetWorkspaceData`, or `GetCharArray` and get nothing. My code:

```
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();            
        string loadCommand = @"zmienne=load('C:\myPath\mat.mat')";
        matlab.Execute(loadCommand);
```

**Done.**

Comment: Does you technique work for conventional variables (string, double, matrix...)? How do you try to access the variables you read back? Doesn't C# need to know the data structure before it can access them? A few more lines of code in your "here is what I tried" would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it does work for convetional variables, but it doesn't for struct. This is first time I work with Matlab and C# together. So far, I haven't any problems, until I have to somehow convert Matlab's struct to C# and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Did you read some of the related articles on the Mathworks site? You could start with http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-structures.html . It may be difficult (given how C# works) to do this without knowing the details of the structure before compiling. How do you hope to access the data?

Answer (score 4):

The [COM interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html) does not [support](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-com-data-in-matlab-software.html#bq4epvg-5) structures or sparse arrays. By that I mean you cannot directly pass those between MATLAB and .NET, if you try you get the following error printed in the MATLAB command window:

> Warning: ActiveX - invalid argument type or value

A workaround is to access the fields of the structure on the MATLAB side, and store each in a variable that can be marshaled back to C# using one of the supported conversion rules.

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // load MAT-file contents into a structure variable
    matlab.Execute("S = load('wind.mat')");

    // get field and store in separate variable
    matlab.Execute("x = S.x;");

    // obtain variable "x" from MATLAB into C#
    var x = (double[,,]) matlab.GetVariable("x", "base");

    // print array in C#
    Console.WriteLine("ndims(x) = {0}, numel(x) = {1}", x.Rank, x.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < x.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x[{0},{1},{2}] = {3}", i, j, k, x[i,j,k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, the MAT-file used contains a bunch of multi-dimensional matrices of `double` type:

```
>> whos -file wind.mat
  Name       Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  u         35x41x15            172200  double              
  v         35x41x15            172200  double              
  w         35x41x15            172200  double              
  x         35x41x15            172200  double              
  y         35x41x15            172200  double              
  z         35x41x15            172200  double
```

The thing to note of course is that when you [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) a MAT-file with an output argument, it will return a structure whos fields are the variables stored in that file:

```
>> S = load('wind.mat')
S = 
    u: [35x41x15 double]
    v: [35x41x15 double]
    w: [35x41x15 double]
    x: [35x41x15 double]
    y: [35x41x15 double]
    z: [35x41x15 double]
```

So you could have loaded the file without specifying an output, that way the variables are directly loaded as separate ones.